# Best practice for Sqlite query building in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I used to build my `Sqlite` complex queries with input parameters by concatenating a `string` value with my parameters and return this `string` with the final executable `query` as following:-

```
public static String getExampleQuery(String id) {
    String query = "SELECT * " + "FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME
            + " as table " + "INNER JOIN " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_TWO
            + " as table2 " + "ON table." + Constants.COL_ID
            + " = table2." + Constants.COL_ID
                            + " and table2." + Constants.COL_ID + " = '"
                            + para1 + "'"
            + " order by table." + Constants.COL_ID + " desc ";
    return query;
}
```

Then, I pass the `query` string to be executed. **BUT**, most of the times I face a lot of problems with this way by forgetting `spaces` or adding extra single quot `'` before and after the outer parameter. It always be hard to figure out the problem from the `logcat`. Besides, the queries are not READABLE at all.

What is the best way to build `Sqlite` queries that make the query Readable and less fault-able and to avoid the previous listed problems!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into: [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html), it makes writing queries less low level. You will find some examples how to start using it here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: In your example he using my traditional way of building query! Contacting string

Comment: He is using SQLiteQueryBuilder, for more examples you have to dig google yourself.

Comment: Try to read the link till the end and you will see what I am talking about :). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I can't read `SQLiteQueryBuilder` code at a glance and I'm very use to reading SQL so I write my queries close to the way you do it. I try to put my returns at a logical place for readability. I also use the `rawQuery` method so that I can separate out any variables and not have to worry about quoting text or not quoting integers.  And I add extra spaces in my queries.. it just keeps me from making common mistakes:

```
String[] whereVars = new String[]{id};
String query = " SELECT * "
             + " FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " as t " 
             + " INNER JOIN " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_TWO + " as t2 " 
             + " ON t." + Constants.COL_ID + " = t2." + Constants.COL_ID
             + " WHERE t2." + Constants.COL_ID + " = ? "
             + " ORDER BY t." + Constants.COL_ID + " DESC ";
db.rawQuery(query, whereVars)
```